# ¿Como cambio de color varios parrafos, titulos etc... Con un class apretando un button?

Tags: javascript

Quiero cambiar de color mis párrafos al apretar un button, pero no se de que manera llamarlos en js sin colocarles un id a cada uno de los elementos en html. No se si estoy llamando mal a mi class desde js o si no se puede...
De esta manera llame a mis id para cambiar los fondos, pero tampoco se si sea correcto y JS:

```
function modoNoc() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    header1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    footer1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Comment: Buscá cómo seleccionar elementos en el DOM por su clase en lugar de su id.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres lo puedes lograr con getElementsByTagName

Al usarlo con un for obtienes todas las etiquetas y  puedes aplicarles el cambio de color.

Te dejo un ejemplo que puede servirte.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p>Párrafo 1</p>
    <p>Párrafo 2</p>
    <p>Párrafo 3</p>
    <button id="cambiaColor" onclick="ponColor()">Pon color</button>
</body>
<script>
    const button = document.getElementById("cambiaColor");
    const titles = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    function ponColor() {
        // Busca y cambia de color todos los title
        for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            titles[i].style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar el color de los párrafos al hacer click en un botón sin asignarles un id a cada uno de los párrafos y poder hacerlo dándoles una clase, puedes hacerlo utilizando querySelectorAll y forEach. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puedes hacerlo:

Primero, pon a los párrafos la misma clase para que puedas seleccionarlos con querySelectorAll. Por ejemplo, vamos a ponerles la clase "parrafo":

```
<p class="parrafo">Este es un párrafo.</p>
<p class="parrafo">Este es otro párrafo.</p>
<p class="parrafo">Este es el tercer párrafo.</p>
```

Luego, en tu función JavaScript, usa querySelectorAll para seleccionar todos los elementos con la clase "parrafo".
Para terminar, cambia los estilos que quieras a todos los "párrafo" usando un forEach:

```
function cambiarColorParrafos() {
   var parrafos = document.querySelectorAll(".parrafo");

   parrafos.forEach(function(e) {
      e.style.color = "red"; // Cambia el color de texto a rojo
      e.style.backgroundColor = "black"; // Cambia el fondo a negro
   });
}
```

Luego, puedes llamar a esta función cuando se presione tu botón:

```
<button onclick="cambiarColorParrafos()">Cambiar Color de Párrafos</button>
```

Cuando hagas clic en el botón, los estilos de todos los párrafos con la clase "parrafo" cambiarán según lo que hayas puesto en la función cambiarColorParrafos. Recuerda ajustar los estilos a tus preferencias.

Comment: Hmmmm... Ciertas palabras me recuerdan a una que otra IA generativa...